# Given an Object from the database, how to remove a single item from the object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a query like so:

```
@users = User.where(:something => 'met')
```

This returns back @users with 1+ items

What I want to do is loop through the @user object to see if a condition is met, if the condition is met I want to delete the item from the object. I've been trying the following but it does not appear to work though does not error.

```
@users.each_with_index do |u, index|
  @users.delete(index) if u.id == 12
end
```

Suggestions on a better way to make this work?

Thank you

Comment: This function will delete random records from your database. I hope you haven't deployed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you want to delete it from the database or just from the list?

In the former case, do

```
@users.each do |u|
  u.delete if u.id == 12
end
```

In the latter, do

```
@users.reject! do |u|
  u.id == 12
end
```

or, if the condition is some method on user returning "true"/"false"-ish values,

```
@users.reject! &:is_12

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def is_12
    self.id == 12
  end
end
```

Comment: By the way, I always prefer to use the select/collect/inject/reject/detect methods, instead of their more varied synonyms (find_all/map/reduce/delete_if/find) because of their beautiful assonance.

Comment: thanks, I want to remove it from the list @users, not the database

Comment: I don't follow what some condition is

Answer (score 0):

[Array#delete_if](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-delete_if) :

```
@users.delete_if { |u| u.id == 12 }
```

You can also exclude it from the query all together:

```
User.where(:something => "met").where("id != ?", 12)
```

The reason your try isn't working is because `Array#delete` takes an object, not an index. So you'd have to tweak your example:

```
@users.each { |u| @users.delete(u) if u.id == 12 }
```

But that seems silly given the `delete_if` method :)

Answer (score 0):

It's usually a better idea to exclude the record in question from your fetch:

```
@users = User.where(:something => 'met').where('id!=?', 12)
```

Otherwise you have to manipulate the result set. An easy way to do this is convert it to a Hash and delete the offending key(s):

```
@users = Hash[User.where(...).collect { |u| [ u.id, u ] }]
@users.delete(12)
```